# Kotlin: setOnFocusChangeListener - use of setter method instead of property access syntax

Tags: kotlin

I know what the warning message means but I am not able to apply it. Here is my code:

```
   edittext_search.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
        if(hasFocus){
            chipgroup.clearCheck()
        }
    }
```

Usually Android Studio cleans up your code automatically but in this case it cannot. Or should I just ignore the warning message anyway?

Comment: which version of Android Studio you are using? I don't see such warning in 3.4.2. Just warning about `parameter v is not used`

Comment: I am using 3.4.1 - I will update now, lets see if it goes away

Comment: .. and it's gone :) @AndreiTanana I can accept it if you write it as an answer. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like just little glitch in Android Studio. Update to latest stable version could help.